# My value keeps on getting set to 1 in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I have been trying to get a difficulty system to work in my game but I have encountered a problem, my float keeps on getting reset to 1, I have the larger script on a prefab that is in another prefab and the small script is one I have on the "DifficultyController". I have tried looking through the files but I cannot find any instance of the number 1 I have also tried making a new prefab to see if that was the problem but still the number 1!

The script in the prefab:

```
public float health;
public GameObject deathEffect;

public float difficulty;

private float destroy;
private void Update()
{
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        //Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    EnemyDifficulty(difficulty);
}
public void TakeDamage (float damage)
{
    health -= damage;
}
public void EnemyDifficulty(float chance)
{
    Debug.Log(chance);
    destroy = Random.Range(0, 50);
    if (destroy <= 3) { Destroy(gameObject); }

    chance = Random.Range(chance / 2, chance * 2);
    Debug.Log(chance);
    if (chance <= 8 && chance >= 3)
    {
        BasicEnemy();
    } 
    if (chance <= 20 && chance >= 8)
    {
        MediumEnemy();
    }
    if(chance <= 3)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroeyed");
    }
}
public void BasicEnemy()
{
    Debug.Log("basic");
}
public void MediumEnemy()
{
    Debug.Log("medium");
}
```

}

Code in the "DifficultyController"

```
public Enemy enemy;

public float difficultye = 5;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    enemy.difficulty = difficultye;
}
```

Comment: Which float?  If it's `difficulty` then you're not showing any code that modifies it except for `DifficultyController.Update() // could the problem be that difficultye is getting modified?`  Please show all relevant code. You seem to have a problem with float comparisons... if `chance == 8` then both `BasicEnemy()` and `MediumEnemy()` get called, ditto for `chance == 3` --> `BasicEnemy()` and `Destroy()`.  Here I'm pretty sure you want to test ranges like this (where b is a boundary value) `a <= chance < b` and `b <= chance < c` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which variable keeps getting set to one, but I assume it's either `health`, `difficulty`, or `difficultye`. This is because they are `public`, meaning that they can be edited in the inspector. If the inspector value differs from the code value, then the inspector value will override that of our code.

You can fix this by changing the variables in editor, marking them as `[System.NonSerialized]`, or setting them to private, depending on which best fits your needs.